# Opencart extension not working

Tags: opencart, checkout

I am trying to use an opencart checkout extension using opencart 1.5.6.4, but even after enabling the checkout extension the old checkout is still the one that's showing. I already tried two checkout extensions using the same opencart version but it won't show up.

This are the steps I did. could anyone check if I missed something? I followed the instructions, but maybe there are things that are not in the instruction manual.

1. I installed opencart 1.5.6.4 and deleted the install folder.
2. Next I copied the upload files from vqmod version 2 and activated itin the group section.
3. Last I copied the extension upload files in my opencart.
4. I installed the extension in the modules and activated it by turning on the "replace the main checkout".

But after those the old checkout is still the one that's showing.

And another question, When I tried uploading the theme there's a file that is named the same, what should I do with that? should I rename it? Won't the programming be destroyed?

I am just a beginner in opencart so your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is error please describe it ?

Comment: Hello,
It doesn't show any error. It just won't show up even after activation.

Comment: please go to system > settings & edit and click last tab "server" find Display Errors: and click to yes. check what is error.

Comment: I checked the system > error logs
and its blank

Comment: check user permission on user group. may be possible.

Comment: I checked the user permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work is because I installed the wrong vqmod, Everything works after that.

If anyone goes through the same problem in the future just check if you're vqmod was installed by typing NAME_OF_SITE/vqmod/install.

It should say:

VQMOD ALREADY INSTALLED!

if this message does not appear install your vqmod.